# Cropping image with Drupal 7 api

Tags: media

I tried below codes but nothing happen.Any ideas?

```
$image = image_load('/home/ok/sites/default/files/20140213030054333.jpg', $toolkit = FALSE);
//print_r($image);
 image_scale_and_crop($image, 350,700);
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a [wild stab in the dark](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_save/7):

```
image_save($image);
```